# Anime with flying fortress and pilot main character

Tags: story-identification, anime

Has a main character who is a pilot of some kind.  There is a chick who rides a bird of some sort and a couple of other guys in mecha or tanks with them.  There is also a flying fortress commanded by a darker skinned woman.  I do remember that the main character crash lands his plane on the flying battleship fortress thing as well and that they team up against another larger group.  Anybody have any idea?

Comment: Chicks prefer to be called ladies nowadays, you neanderthal.

Comment: This is one of the vaguest descriptions. Could you add any details? Names of characters? When you read/watched it? etc. Good luck.

Comment: @Valorum: I was assuming that the bird-riding creature was a baby bird.  And, for all we know, "Chris" is a woman.  Or a bird.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  By the way, Chris, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange.

Comment: I edited your question to put the main details of the anime in the title. Feel free to revert if that changes your answer too much.

Comment: By a "flying fortress" you mean something like [a B-17](http://www.boeing.com/history/products/b-17-flying-fortress.page)?

Answer (score 2):

Sound an awful lot like 1981's [Heavy Metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_%28film%29), which was an anthology of stories united by a theme:

- chick who rides a bird: Taarna (also see the cover art, and the South Park parody):

[image]

- Main character who is a pilot of some kind: Could be the opening vignette or the taxicab driver segment ("[Harry Canyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_(film)#Harry_Canyon)")
- Flying fortress (though not commanded by a woman), "[B-17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_(film)#B-17)"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind.  But in that the girl flew on a mechanical wing and there were a bunch of multi eyed bugs that lived in the polluted lands.  If I recall there was a flying fortress.  The main characyer was the girl though.